# Page of Milnor I don't understand

Tags: differential-topology

At page 22, when proving the "Homotopy lemma", Milnor uses the fact that $|f^{-1}(y) + g^{-1}(y)| =|f^{-1}(y)| + |g^{-1}(y)|$, (thus he concludes that $0\equiv \partial F = |f^{-1}(y)| + |g^{-1}(y)|$, i.e. the thesis). I don't see why this should be true, what assures that $|f^{-1}(y) \cap g^{-1}(y)|$ is zero?

Comment: Page $22$ of what?  What is $f$?  what is $g$? Does $|\cdots |$ denote absolute value or cardinality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is a misrepresentation of what Milnor is doing. He has $F^{-1}(y)\cap M\times\{0\} = f^{-1}(y)\times \{0\}$ and $G^{-1}(y)\cap M\times \{1\} = g^{-1}(y)\times\{1\}$. The two sets are disjoint because of the different $t$ coordinates.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much

Comment: You’re welcome. You should accept the answer unless you have further questions.